# Using map in React returns an array equal to the last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So I'm new to React. I'm trying to use the function map to give an id to an array of objects in the state of a Component. But when I iterate over the objects in the function, the resulting array's elements are all equal to each other, which are equal to the last one iterated. I'm using the uuid module to add the unique ids. This is what I have inside the Component, with a better explanation inside comments:

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    classes: Array(5).fill({
      id: null,
      name: null
    }),
  }
}

componentWillMount() {

  // This console.log, strangely, logs the state of the Component as if
  // this componentWillMount function had already been executed, showing the
  // classes with their ids (still the wrong ones). Would appreciate it if
  // someone explained that
  console.log(this.state.classes)

  let classThings = this.state.classes.map(classObject => {
    let obj = classObject
    obj.id = uuid.v4()
    // This logs the object correctly. The console shows, thanks to this,
    // five different objects with five different ids
    console.log(obj)
    return obj
  })

  this.setState({
    classes: classThings
  })

  // But, for some reason, this one logs the array and all the elements
  // inside are equal to te last one logged by the previous console.log 
  // that is inside the map function, when it should log an array with the
  // five different elements
  console.log(classThings)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `Array#fill` is setting all of the elements in the array to the same object, so the most recent change will be what the object contains.

Comment: @4castle thanks for the response. But I'm only using it once in the constructor, it would affect even if I'm using setState precisely for all of them not to be equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element in your array `classes` point to the same object (because `Array.fill` just sets every element in the array to the single object you passed it), so when you make a change to any object in `classes`, you're changing every object in `classes`. You can use `map` to create a new object for each element instead:

Replace

```
Array(5).fill({
   id: null,
   name: null
})
```

With

```
Array(5).fill(null).map(() => ({
   id: null,
   name: null
}))
```

With this change, you could also give each object in `classes` a unique id when you create it instead of in `componentWillMount`:

```
Array(5).fill(null).map(() => ({
   id: uuid.v4(),
   name: null
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

All elements are same in `this.state.classes`. That means

```
this.state.classes[0] === this.state.classes[1] // true
```

And since you are mutating the object of array inside `map`, that change is being reflected to all the elements of array because they all point to the same object eventually. That meanse is all iteration

```
let classThings = this.state.classes.map(classObject => {
    let obj = classObject
    obj.id = uuid.v4()
    console.log(this.state.classes[0].id === this.state.classes[1].id) // true
    return obj
  })
```

You should avoid mutating the object and create new object everytime to get desired result

```
let classThings = this.state.classes.map(classObject => {
    let obj = Object.assign({}, classObject)
    obj.id = uuid.v4()
    console.log(this.state.classes[0].id === this.state.classes[1].id) // true
    return obj
  })
```